# Udp ports are not showing open state

Tags: linux

I have done udp port scanning using nmap in kali Linux.But every time I 'm getting  open | filtered ports state but my udp ports are open.Can u please suggest me any solution for this.

Comment: it is showing open | filtered for both open and closed ports .

Answer (score 2):

If the application attached to the port doesn't reply anything, it would be impossible to determine whether the port is open or filtered.

In UDP, data is essentially "fire and forget". Unreliable delivery. There is no way to know whether the packet got dropped by a firewall/router/etc, or if it arrived but the application doesn't respond.

Comment: The udp  port is open that I know from another tool but why I 'm not getting it through nmap ,still getting open | filtered  ports states of udp ports.Is there any other solution for this.

Comment: Is there any other tool in kali Linux for this?